# How to you change the locale of a flutter app while running?

Tags: flutter, localization

I'm using

```
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart'; //For Cupertino stuff
import 'package:localization/localization.dart'; //For actual translations
import 'package:intl/intl.dart'; //For locales
```

to localize my flutter app.  It comes up in the language the phone is set to, but I'd like to add a way to change the language within th e app...I tried using `LocalJsonLocalization.delegate.load(locale(lang))` from a button (for now; I'd like to use a dropdown list box but that doesn't seem to be null safe yet), but that didn't actually make the change (I saw the debug log and it said it couldn't load the json language file)...

Comment: You need update data `locale` in `MaterialApp` use any state management you want

Comment: you can use ```easyLocalization``` package. Quite easy to use and you don't need any state management to update the language.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your `MaterialApp` in a `BlocBuilder`.

```dart
return BlocBuilder<MainBloc, MainState>(
  builder: (context, mainState) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      locale: mainState.locale,
      supportedLocales: L10n.all,
      localizationsDelegates: [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
    );
```

Then from your button just call the **Bloc Event** that will change the **state** of the **locale**.

Do not forget to add:

```dart
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

at the beginning of `main()` function

It should also work fine using Provider.